# Bubble Sort - Swap Counter method

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, cs50

I am studying algorithms. Next year I am going to university to study Computer Science, so that's why I am trying to learn something before classes start.

At the moment I am studying the bubble sort algorithm and its behavior.

I watched a video on YouTube posted by the CS50 course at Harvard and I am trying to follow their pseudocode. I have already found bubble sort algorithms online that use 2 for loops. But in the video I watched they use a while loop with a swapcounter and one one for loop. I really want to follow their procedure. You can watch the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ui97-_n5xjo&index=13&list=PLhQjrBD2T3816xq7BHLh4Yj6-v0TnvsrT

This is what I have.

```
int main() {

    int numbers[7] = {2, 7, 6, 3, 1, 5, 4};

    int swapCounter = 1;
    int swaps = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    while (swapCounter != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i == 5; i = i + 1) {

            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
                temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
                numbers[i+1] = temp;
                swaps = swaps + 1;
            }
            swapCounter = swaps;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", numbers[0]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[1]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[2]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[3]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[4]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[5]);
    printf("%d\n", numbers[6]);
}
```

I have also use the debugger and I have found that the program is stuck in the `for` loop.

Comment: 1) `i == 5;` is wrong. 2) `swapCounter` or `swaps` need reset each inner-loop.

Comment: what do I have to do? but I have to compare the number five with the value of i. It is not an assignment right?

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/04rvRt)

Comment: Still doesnt work. now it is stuck in the if statement.

Comment: Can you explain _doesnt work_? Did you see the result of the [link](http://ideone.com/04rvRt)?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.  Readers don't care who you are you should not thank them.  Ideally your question would be like: "I want to implement bubblesort with a swap counter. I have a version without: <code>. This is what I have tried: <code>. However the problem is <whatever>."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (swapCounter != 0){
    **swaps = 0;**
    for (int i = 0; i < 7 - 1; i = i + 1) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
            numbers[i+1] = temp;
            swaps = swaps + 1;
        }
    }
    **swapCounter = swaps;**
}
```